# How to exclude certain emails from custom bundle in Google Inbox?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I have a custom bundle set up based on a "to" address.  However, there are certain emails sent to this address that I want to *exclude* from the bundle (since they get bundled to another, lower-priority bundle).  Is there a way to do that?  I tried [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/inbox/UEkbumq2WBg) suggestion but it didn't work... :(

Essentially looking for something like:

```
Bundle: My Billing Bundle
Rules:
  - To: billing@example.com      # everything to billing
  - From: -service@paypal.com    # EXCEPT for stuff from PayPal
```

Here's what I've tried:

[image]

And it's not working (I've also tried swapping the order of those two rules).  It sends *all* of my email to the bundle except for the stuff from PayPal.

Comment: **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding them as two separate rules, they need to be combined into one rule. The behavior you want is AND.

1) Click "ADD"

[image: start]

2) Note the second box, labeled "And..."

[image]

3) Add `-service@paypal.com` to "From"

[image]

4) Click "And..." and then select "To" and add `billing@directangular.com`

[image]

5) You should see `*from* -service@paypal.com *and to* billing@directangular.com` in ONE RULE, instead of having them separated like you showed in your screenshot.

[image]

Comment: So the `from -` works for you in conjunction with a `to`?  `-` alone works for me as well, it just doesn't work when there's also a `to`...

Comment: @mgalgs I looked into this more closely and believe I've now solved your issue. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `-service@paypal.com` to `!service@paypal.com`